# Is it legal to use facebook profile photo

Tags: facebook, web, profile

Is it legal to create a web application where users can paste a facebook profile url and app will download and present a profile photo from that link ? An application won't be storing any data of that user.

Answer (score -1):

No, you can´t do that because:

- Scraping is not allowed, and that´s what you would need to do.
- You can´t be sure if the user who posted the URL is the owner of the profile, he may just paste ANY URL. So the user who owns the profile may not have authorized you to use it.

The proper way to get the profile photo is to authorize the user in your App and use the `/me/picture` endpoint.

Comment: Even if you only show the profile picture and do not store the data on your own database ?  (by default to see the profile picture you don't have to own  a facebook account )

Comment: that would still be scraping - see the first point in my answer. it really does not matter if something is public on facebook, that does not mean you can use it for anything.

Comment: also, what´s the use case if you only show it anyway? sounds pointless to me.

Comment: I had an idea to create some kind of simple matching app and use it to generate more traffic on my site. But I see It will be illegal. Nvm thanks !